# Cluster / group counting algorithm on live grid

Tags: algorithm, grid, cluster-analysis, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a circular grid of ~2700 cells that represent the face of a detector.  This grid is live, constantly updating, so we need to find clusters of hits with a couple microseconds.

Each cell is either a hit or a miss (0 or 1), and a cluster is a grouping of these hit cells that has a distinct perimeter.  I want to count the number of clusters of hit cells very quickly so that we can save the data from events with a certain number of clusters (2) and toss out everything else.

Some algorithms currently in use rely on assigning a value for the number of hit neighbors to the cell.  This is too slow because it requires all of the hit crystals to be identified before the clusters may be identified.  Another, much prettier algorithm that works in parallel is based on the number of turns around a given perimeter of a cluster.  It's really ***quite clever***, so here's the link to the paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168900295007997  This paper also has an image of an ideal grid with clusters.

Most of the posts / papers I've read take data and apply markov chains or some other offline processing to create clusters of data-- we're looking for the opposite.  We want to identify clusters of cells that we already have, and fast.

How might we find these clusters faster?  Any tips or ideas to put me in the right (or a) direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Do cells update one by one or do updates happen in bulk?

Comment: Have you tried grid aggregation based approaches? Think of a quad tree, for example.